# How to grab a variable from the for loop and use it outside the loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am making a strategy game like Europa Universalis 4 but for exploring the New World. It works fine but the issue I kept having was frame drops. I found this was due to having all that code running in the `for` loop all the time. I want to be able to use that `colonyID` variable outside the `for` loop so I don't have to loop through those functions all the time. Is there any way I could do this? Code is below:

```
            for(colonySelected in colonySelectButtons) {
                let colonyID = undefined
                colonyID = colonySelectButtons[colonySelected]
                colonyID.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                    let colonyName = this.id
                    colonyName = colonyName.slice(0, colonyName.length -7) 
                    console.log(colonyName)
                    bannerTransition(colonyName, 55, 75, 75, 0)
                    changeInfoBox("dataBox", colonyName + " (" + nationNames[curSession[colonyName].owner] + ")", "bold", nationBackgroundColors[curSession[colonyName].owner], nationTextColors[curSession[colonyName].owner], "Colony Level - " + curSession[colonyName].colonyLevel, "normal", "Population - " + curSession[colonyName].population, "normal", "Defense - " + curSession[colonyName].defense, "normal")
                    setData("Varvodia", "Arnieria", "Wigia", "Nenichia", "Bascia", "Szentia", "Enparadia", "Sacher", "Wiland", "Sasbach", "Feldia", "Momonykia", "Adyoujdia", "Ormatvaria", "Ataszek", "Kouni", "Luruvojia", "Ayburt", "Gond")
                    colonyID.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
                        bannerTransition(colonyName, 45, 65, 100, 10)
                        document.getElementById("dataBox").style.display = "none"
                    })
                    colonyID.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        minimap_ERASE("Varvodia", "Arnieria", "Wigia", "Nenichia", "Bascia", "Szentia", "Enparadia", "Sacher", "Wiland", "Sasbach", "Feldia", "Momonykia", "Adyoujdia", "Ormatvaria", "Ataszek", "Kouni", "Luruvojia", "Ayburt", "Gond")
                        document.getElementById(colonyName + "_miniMap").style.stroke = "white"
                        changeColonyBox(colonyName, curSession[colonyName].img.city,  playerFlags[curSession[colonyName].owner])
                        document.getElementById("colony-info").innerHTML = "</div><div style='margin-top: 0px'><div style='color: white; display: inline-block;'>" + curSession[colonyName].population + "</div> Settlers</div><div><div style='color: white; display: inline-block;'>" + curSession[colonyName].defense + "</div> Defenders</div>"
                        moveInterface("colonyUI", 0.25, 0, 10, 30, 0)
                        soundEmiter(clicks.colony.city, 0.5, true)
                        soundEmiter(clicks.hover.mid, 0.75, false)
                        fog_EFFECT("Varvodia", "Arnieria", "Wigia", "Nenichia", "Bascia", "Szentia", "Enparadia", "Sacher", "Wiland", "Sasbach", "Feldia", "Momonykia", "Adyoujdia", "Ormatvaria", "Ataszek", "Kouni", "Luruvojia", "Ayburt", "Gond")
                        document.getElementById(colonyName + "_colony_outline").setAttribute("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0)")
                        mapTransition(0.25)
                        if(curSession[colonyName].owner === curPlayer.nation) {
                            resizeInterface("colonyUI", 320, 400)
                            displayInterface("colony-build", display_IB)
                            displayInterface("colony-recruit", display_IB)
                        } else {
                            resizeInterface("colonyUI", 320, 350)
                            displayInterface("colony-build", display_NONE)
                            displayInterface("colony-recruit", display_NONE)
                        }
                    })
                    // clicks.hover.mid.play()
                })
            }
```

If anyone to interested to see what the program looks like or wants to test it, use this link to my Heroku application: https://obscure-chamber-04640.herokuapp.com/ This way you can see what I am talking about in frame drops.

NOTE: The functions in the eventListener are just external functions that I made for the program. I just want to make those eventListeners work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move
`let colonyID = undefined`
outside the for-loop.

Comment: See that kind of works but when I do, it only works for one of my colonies in the SVG. All the other ones break.

Comment: Why not select all colonies at once using something like querySelectorAll() and adding the event listener to each one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using the for loop entirely I suggest you give the `colonySelectButtons` element that contains all the menu buttons an 'id' 
and then bind it to an event listener and then use `e.target`  `addEventListener("mouseover", function(e)` to handle each element clicked 
here is a little code to demonstrate what I mean 
 **i have changed it and put the correct link** 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/ov8gnL4h/).